# How to compose CakePHP model query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have the following situation in my model:

```
-a "users" table, with "id" as primary key
-a "stores" table with "id" as primary key, and "users_id" as foreign key
-a "promos" table with "id" as primary key, and "stores_id" as foreign key
```

So in other words, each promo belongs to only 1 store, and each store belongs to only 1 user, and the relationships are set in the model files.

I would like to create a action/view that will allow a logged-in user to only see his own promos, but I'm not sure how.

The following code gets me an error message because "User.id" is not part of the promos table, however I don't know how to create parameters what will limit the promo list only to stores owned by this user.

```
$allPromos = $this->Promo->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Store.id' => $storeId, 'Store.enabled' => 1, 'User.id' => $this->Session->read('id'))));
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your model structure is a little weird. Right now it looks like each store belongs only to one user and each promo belongs to only one store. If that's correct, make sure that your model associations are correct.
You're finding them from the user here, so User.php needs `var $hasMany = array('Store')` and Store.php needs `var $hasMany = array('Promo')`

```
$allPromos = $this->User->find('all', 
                               array('fields' => array('Promo.*'),
                                     'contain' => array('Store', 'Promo'),
                                     'recursive' => 2 //Two levels of recursion to get from User to Store to Promo
                                     'conditions' => 
                                     array('Store.id' => $storeId, 
                                           'Store.enabled' => 1, 
                                           'User.id' => $this->Session->read('id'))));
```

Comment: Yes, each promo belongs to only 1 store, and each store belongs to only 1 user, and the relationships are set in the model files like you mention. I'm getting the following (the Promo model, and promos table, do exist):

Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'Promo'

SQL Query: SELECT `Promo`.*, `User`.`id` FROM `truoff_truoff`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `Store`.`id` = 15 AND `Store`.`enabled` = 1 AND `User`.`id` = 1

Comment: That's pretty weird. The SQL being generated is the problem, it's selecting only from the users table, but it should be generating joins because of the recursive and contain clauses. Try this:
`$this->User->Store->Promo->find('all', array('conditions' => THE CONDITIONS ARRAY ABOVE));`

Comment: Yep, this is working, but with Store.user_id instead of User.id as above. $allPromos = $this->User->Store->Promo->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Store.id' => $storeId, 'Store.enabled' => 1, 'Store.user_id' => $this->Session->read('id')))); Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In PromosController:

```
$this->Promo->find('all', array(
                          'conditions'=>array(
                             'Store.user_id'=>$this->Session->read('id'),
                             'Store.enabled'=>1),
                          'contain'=>array('Store'));
```

In UsersController get information about User, his Stores and Promos):

```
$this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array(
    'User.id' => $this->Session->read('id'),
    'Store.enabled' => 1),
  'contain'=>array('Store'=>'Promo')
));
```